# My modal is not appearing, having difficulty targeting a button within a table using selectors

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to have a "Delete confirm Modal" appear when clicking the delete button next to each row in a table. I'm not sure if its an issue with my JavaScript or the HTML.

```
$("#confirmDelete delete").on("click", function () {
            $("#confirmDelete").modal('show');
        });

        $("delete").on("click", function () {
            console.log("Ive been pushed");
            var button = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Services/DeleteService/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                method: "DELETE",
                success: function () {
                    $(button.parent("tr")).remove();
                    console.log("Success");
                }
            });
        });


<table id="services" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        @foreach (var service in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@service.Name</td>
                <td><button id="edit" class="btn btn-info edit">Edit</button>  <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-service-id=@service.Id data-target="#confirmDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery selector on line 4 is looking for a delete tag instead of a delete class - its trying to find something like

```
<delete></delete>
```

If you want to add a click handler to the delete button, add a '.' before the selector to tell jQuery to find an element with the class 'delete', instead of the type of 'delete'. For example:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () {
```

The '.' will look for elements with a class of delete.

P.S. your delete confirmation button will have the same problem, if you're looking for one with a class of 'delete'.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!

Comment: No problem! Good luck.